# Specific part of mesh rotated when exporting to unity

Tags: mesh, unity

I have a sniper rifle mesh that is divided into different parts (body, stock, scope, etc). I have this magazine mesh that has a magazine bone that it is parented to. I have rotated the mesh and armature so to compensate for the blender-unity rotation ([Following this guide](https://blog.imphenzia.com/blender-to-unity/)), which has worked for other meshes before. Everything is fine except the magazine, which has a weird rotation that is not there in blender. Does anyone know any possible explanations and how I can fix this?

All transforms are applied.

[image: The mesh in Unity]

Comment: Blender is Z-up and Unity is Y-up, could that have something to do with it? You can specify the conversion in the export settings (for most formats) if necessary. What type of file are you exporting to?

Comment: try joining all the mesh using CTRL J to make it a single object and export

Comment: Do your rig have a main root bone?

Comment: I'm exporting using a FBX. The armature has a "body" bone, which controls the stock, barrel, body, and scope. The body bone is a parent of the magazine bone, rifle bolt bone, and a left hand position bone.

Comment: Combining all the meshes doesn't seem to help. The magazine is still rotated.

Comment: Also to add on, this seems to specifically be a blender unity problem, as exporting the rifle to a different blender project and importing it causes no problems.

Comment: I found the solution. For some reason, unlike the other projects, doing the rotation fix on the guide causes the magazine to rotate weirdly. So I specified the up and forward directions when I exported. No idea why that works but that's the solution I found.